# how do I make erase everything off of local repo and merge in new repo?

Tags: git

I pulled off of the Master branch but forgot to build a new branch on my local repo before making changes. I don't mind losing the changes on my local repo, I just want to go back to the original Master as I got it. If I do a git pull, will that make me go through all the differences that I've made? How do I just ignore those differences if it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy, and best of all, you don't have to lose any of your changes:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git branch new-branch-name-for-changes
$ git reset --hard origin/master
$ git pull
```

Your changes will be saved on the new branch.